# preg_match - extract only numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like `Results 1 - 20 of 400`.

Considering this example, i need to get `1`, `20` and `400` to 3 distinct variables.

I'm trying this code without success:

```
preg_match('/\d{1,}/', $text, $array);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$text = "Results 1 - 20 of 400";
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $text, $array);
        //^^^^ Note here! 'preg_match_all' not 'preg_match' to get all matches! (Your regex would also work '/\d{1,}/')
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 [2] => 400 ) )
```

For more information about `preg_match_all()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

And a quote from there:

> preg_match_all — Perform a **global** regular expression match